# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' when uploaded into the hosting server

Tags: php, syntax-error, wamp

I am using WAMP to develop my PHP based project and when using it no error appear. But after uploading it to hosting server, this error appears,

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /data/multiserv/users/830768/projects/1970916/www/index.php on line 6
```

The code in line 6 is as following

```
render("/event_view.php",["title" => "Current Events","rows"=>$rows]);
```

The render function is predefined and accepting the variables without an error in WAMP. I was searching other threads but the examples were not very clear ( I am not a expert in PHP). can anyone help me. I have little time to upload this to server and make this workig as this is a school project. Thank You!

Comment: What PHP versions are you running on your WAMP server and on the webhost?

Comment: What version of PHP do you have locally? What version is on the hosting server?

Comment: Hosting they say PHP5. its a free hosting server so it seems they dont give much information.

Comment: @eyeris - you can find out by using `phpinfo()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That array syntax was introduced in PHP 5.4. It's likely that you're using a new version of PHP, while the host is using an old one. If so, then you can use the old array syntax, which works on both versions:

```
render("/event_view.php", array("title" => "Current Events", "rows" => $rows));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems the errors are with the version. But it takes a lot of time to change code from newer version to older one. However I am really thankful.

Comment: @rid After working from 8pm till 8am in the morning, i made an upload and was slammed with this error - was at wits end and then i found your answer. Beer worthy post! Thank you!